# ASP.NET Core RBAC mixed with Client Credentials Flow (OIDC)

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, rbac

I have AWS Cognito Identity Provider, a Client (React App) and Resource Server (ASP.NET Core API). React App authenticates a User and gets `id token` and `access token`, passing only `access token` to the API. I want to have RBAC and I'm able to implement it by relying on `cognito:groups` claim that is part of access_token for all User identities (`username` or `sub` is also there). Now I can have

```
[Authorize(Role="Admin")]
```

above my ASP.NET Core controller or action and here we go. So far so good.
access token (Authorization Code flow):

```
{
  "sub": "1cefa8a3-0e2a-475b-b7fb-98a725e7d8ef",
  "cognito:groups": [
    "admins"
  ],
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "openid profile",
  "auth_time": 1605409754,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_wHXN*",
  "exp": 1605413354,
  "iat": 1605409754,
  "version": 2,
  "jti": "458deaeb-3b89-4f57-827a-85efd024f703",
  "client_id": "2a232opiiuprvh1aq5pge04d49",
  "username": "Google_113965211412849195444"
}
```

But then I need to implement a scheduled job that uses the API also and has no User in the context of the execution. That is what Client Credentials flow supposed to be used for... But now that it's not a User, but rather a Client (impersonated) the access token is passed to the API have neither `username` nor `cognito:groups` claims in it. There is only `scope` claim that can be used for authorization purposes it seems...

access token (Client Credentials):

```
{
  "sub": "1qpfdgsigoe4f7ii6tq0k4dlfg",
  "token_use": "access",
  "scope": "my_scope",
  "auth_time": 1605437870,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_wHX*",
  "exp": 1605441470,
  "iat": 1605437870,
  "version": 2,
  "jti": "7014d021-13c8-42c0-b9e7-4c80fefcbf2e",
  "client_id": "1qpfdgsigoe4f7ii6tq0k4dlfg"
}
```

So, my questions are:

1. What's the best practice is this case ? Is it OK to write a custom authorization policy to check for both user-based tokens (and use Roles and probably scope claims) and check for non-User tokens (and rely on scope only)
2. Is there any example or a guideline for RBAC with Client Credentials?

Thanks